# Pytorch Transform library explaination

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

`transforms.Normalize([0.5]*3, [0.5]*3)`

Can someone help me to understand what this and how it works?

Comment: May you format the code to improve readability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the documentation for the `Normalize`transform [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize). It says : Normalize a tensor image with mean and standard deviation. Given mean: `(mean[1],...,mean[n])` and std: `(std[1],..,std[n])` for `n` channels, this transform will normalize each channel of the input `torch.Tensor` i.e., `output[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]`

So in your case, you are constructing a `Normalize` transform with `mean=std=[0.5,0.5,0.5]`. This means that you are expecting an input with 3 channels, and for each channel you want to normalize with the function

```
x -> (x-0.5)/0.5 = 2x-1
```